# Using if while creating for loop

Tags: c

I am getting a number from the user to print a pattern in C language. If the number is an odd number there is no problem; but, if the number is an even number, codes are printing 1 block more! So, I want to check whether the number is an even number in my `for` loop.

I tried this code but it didnt work:

```
for (i = 1; i <= numb + 2; i++) {

    if (numb% 2 == 0) {
        numb+= 1;
    }

    for (j = 0; (numb % 2 == 0) ? (j < numb) : (j < numb+ 1); j++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            printf("* %d * ", j);       
        }
        else {
            printf("***** ");
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: i solved the problem with editing the first for loop. my pattern working correctly now. thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the syntax of your second statement (the conditional "test") in your `for` loop. You need to rearrange the code so this is a ***single*** statement:

```
for (j = 0; j < ( (numb % 2 == 0) ? numb : numb + 1 ); j++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand why but its going to endless loop and not printing the pattern correctly

Comment: @altayyyy To answer you more fully, I'll need to see more of your code! Like where `numb` is being defined at what's going on inside the `for` loop.

Comment: In the code you just posted, the `if (numb % 2 == 0) { numb += 1; } ` block makes sure that the subsequent test of `(numb % 2 == 0)` will ***never*** be true. So, what's the rub?

Comment: `(numb % 2 == 0) ? (j < numb) : (j < numb+ 1)` is also a single expression, no? But I agree that the real problem is in the overall code. Perhaps the OP can clarify what the desired output should look like for a given input of `numb`?

Comment: @MOehm I'm not an expert on actual definitions of statements and expressions, but the code you just quoted has ***two separate*** comparisons on `j` (albeit, only one will actually run) - and I'm not sure you can have that syntax as the 'control` statement in a `for` loop.

Comment: i solved the problem with editing the first for loop. my pattern working correctly now. thanks everyone for help.